# Closed-form Expression of the Partition Function $p(n)$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, integer-partitions

I feel like I have seen news that a paper was recently published, at most a few months ago, that solved the well-known problem of finding a closed-form expression for the partition function $p(n)$ which enumerates the number of integer partitions of $n$: does anybody have the reference of this paper?

And if not a closed-form exactly, then I seem to recall some significant advance was made recently: can you provide any bibliography (2010, 2011)?

Hopefully this will ring a bell with someone...

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for Bruinier and Ono's recent paper [Algebraic formulas for the coefficients of half-integral weight harmonic weak Maass forms](http://www.aimath.org/news/partition/brunier-ono.pdf). It received a lot of [publicity](http://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2011-01/eu-nmt011911.php) recently.

Comment: Thanks! That's it!! (And the link to the publicity was helpful in determining this was what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather unkown expression obtained by G.Iommi Amunátegui: *A non-recursive expression for the number of irreducible representations of the symmetric group $S_n$*", Physica 114A (1982), 361-364, which gives $p(n)$.

Comment: The paper is available here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2098. But as far as I can tell, there is no proof, just a conjecture based on some tabulated values...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will get an "elementary" closed form but [JM Ain't A Mathematician](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/498/j-m-aint-a-mathematician) was able to find a sequence of different continuations of the partition function whose limit looks increasingly well behaved. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/feeding-real-or-even-complex-numbers-to-the-integer-partition-function-pn)

Computing the limit as his $\rho \rightarrow 1$ and then computing a taylor series of the resultant function seems like an attack for producing a non recursive formula for evaluating partitions.