# Closed form Formula for Partitions of an Integer

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I happened across the following question:

> Determine the number of ways of putting $m$ indistinguishable balls
>   into $n$ indistinguishable boxes with the restriction that no box is empty.

The obvious answer is $\Pi(m,n)$, where $\Pi$ denotes the partition of the positive integer $m$ into $n$ parts. This is not "satisfying". Is there a closed form formula for this $\Pi(m,n)$?

Comment: JM's answer here might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/feeding-real-or-even-complex-numbers-to-the-integer-partition-function-pn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no *known* closed form for the partition function. Here is the [sequence on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000041), and also the [Wolfram MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) on this subject is very thorough.

Although, looking at [this MathSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48075/closed-form-expression-of-the-partition-function-pn), I might be wrong ...

Comment: Perfect- just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48075/closed-form-expression-of-the-partition-function-pn) also.

Comment: There is a formula for the number of partitions of a finite set though. The generating function is $e^{e^{x}-1}$.