# Has anyone found a closed-form expression for the strict partition function?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

More precisely, if anyone has found it, could they provide links, please? I have been trying to find such a solution and have not seen one.

For context, when I try to solve the strict partition function for n = 10 billion, but only for triplets, my understanding is that the brute-force method would have me find all the distinct sets of triplets that sum to 10 billion. This becomes ever increasingly expensive as n gets bigger. This is why I am curious if anyone has a solution. To get the complete strict partition value of n, I would need to also calculate all the pairs, quadruplets, etc, right?Thank you!

Comment: Have you searched online for articles about the problem? If you have the answers for several small number cases, https://oeis.org/ might help.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48075/closed-form-expression-of-the-partition-function-pn/4803029#4803029